# Python 3 - sum of all numbers in a file

Tags: python, file

I have a directory consisting of many files, each having  of the format :

```
Vertie,F,5
Wilma,F,17
John,M,11
William,M,15
```

for all the files i need to check if a particular name occurs at a specific line number. If it does then get the sum of the 3rd column for 'F'.

I have written the following code but it doesn't seem to work :

```
        f1 = open('abc.txt')
        f2 = open('abc.txt')
        for i, line in enumerate(f1):
            line = line.strip()
            name, sex, count = line.split(',')
            if i == 2 and name == 'Wilma':
                for line in f2:
                    line = line.strip()
                    name, sex, count = line.split(',')
                    if sex == 'F':
                        result += int(count.strip())
```

Any tips as to where i am going wrong?

Comment: The code doesn't seem to make much sense... Why is `Wilma` hardcoded? Why do you iterate with two iterators over your file?

Comment: Could you be a touch more specific than *"it doesn't seem to work"*?

Comment: Re-work the question please. Example input and output might help. "check if a particular name occurs at a specific line number. If it does then get the sum of the 3rd column for 'F'" - sorry but this doesn't mean much.

Comment: @CommuSoft i am trying to see if at line 2 of the file there is a string called 'Wilma'. If its there then get the sum of 3rd coloumn for where sex = 'F'

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you're using Python for this?  It's pretty simple in `awk`:

```
 awk -F, 'BEGIN{sum=0}/Wilma/{sum+=$3} END{print sum}' file1 file2 ...
```

**Edit based on comment**: Just to be safe, you can explicitly check that the first field is Wilma:

```
 awk -F, '{if($1=="Wilma"){sum+=$3}} END{print sum}' file1 file2 ...
```

Comment: Perhaps use the `^` identifier for `Wilma`? One never knows if additional columns are added (like Surname).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with arbitrary names, genders, and line numbers; consider this:

```
def verify(filename, line_number, line_name, line_sex, result):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            i = i+1
            line = line.strip()
            name, sex, count = line.split(',')
            if not bool(set([i, name, sex]) - set([line_number, line_name, line_sex])):
                result += int(count)
    return result
```

With this, you can check any line for name and gender.

```
# starting point
result = 0

# check if line 2 is a female named Wilma
result = verify('abc.txt', 2, 'Wilma', 'F', result)

print(result) # prints 17
```

You can do this with any line, name, or gender, and the result will keep rising until you reset it.